# Enviar e Remover do banco com Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, mysqli

Olá! Eu recentemente fiz um outro post aqui, mas ficou mal explicado.

Eu estava querendo fazer um formulário que faz um insert no banco e também remove.

Criei um pequeno sistema de títulos, para usuários poderem favoritar os que mais gostaram. Funciona da seguinte forma: O usuário faz o login, procura pelo título que ele curte e ao clicar no botão favoritar é feito um insert, a página recarrega e aparece o botão remover pois eu fiz um mysqli_num_rows, pra dizer se tem ou não uma linha da mesma id do título e usuário.

```html
                   <form method="POST">
                   <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" name="id_titulo">
                   <?php
                     $amigos = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM favoritos WHERE usuario='$login_cookie' AND titulo='$id'");
                     $amigoss = mysqli_fetch_assoc($amigos);
                     if (mysqli_num_rows($amigos)>=1 AND $amigoss["favoritado"]=="sim") {
                       ?>
                       <label for="remover" class="remover">
                       <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                       </label>
                        <input type="submit" value="Remover" name="remover" id="remover" hidden>
                         <?php
                       }else{
                         ?>
                         <label for="favoritar" class="favoritar">
                         <i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                         </label>

                       <input type="submit" name="add" value="Favoritar" id="favoritar" hidden>
                       <?php
                     }
                   ?>

                 </form>
```

```html
<?php


function add(){
  $login_cookie = $_COOKIE['login'];
   if (!isset($login_cookie)) {
     header("Location: index.php");
   }
    include('conexao.php');


    $id_titulo = $_POST["id_titulo"];
    $ins = "INSERT INTO favoritos (usuario, titulo, favoritado) VALUES ('".$login_cookie."', '".$id_titulo."','sim')";

    if(mysqli_query($con, $ins)) {

   ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  location.href='titulo.php?id='+id_titulo;
</script>
    <?php
   } else {
       echo "Erro ao favoritar!";
        echo mysqli_error($con);
   }
}

?>

<?php

  function remove(){
    $login_cookie = $_COOKIE['login'];
    if (!isset($login_cookie)) {
      header("Location: login.php");
    }

    include('conexao.php');

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $saberr = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM titulo WHERE id='$id'");
    $saber = mysqli_fetch_assoc($saberr);
    $titulo = $saber['id'];

    $ins = "DELETE FROM favoritos WHERE usuario='$login_cookie' AND titulo='$titulo'";
    $conf = mysqli_query($con, $ins) or die(mysqli_error());
    if ($conf) {
      header("Location: titulo.php?id=".$id);
    }else{
      echo "<h3>Erro ao remover...</h3>";
    }
  }

?>
```

Esse é o código com o PHP puro, mas ele recarrega a página toda vez que eu favorito e removo, e eu queria que na hora do clique ele não recarregasse a página toda. Eu até tinha conseguido fazer um insert com AJAX, vendo uns videos no youtube, mas não consegui remover. Eu queria saber como eu faria pra agora remover e se a condição que eu fiz pode ser usada no Jquery.

Comment: Não ficou muito claro ainda a pergunta. Achei confuso a parte do IF e ELSE que está dentro do FORM. Poderia especificar melhor o código inteiro, principalmente a parte do HTML. Acredito também que poderia ser feito uma segunda página para confirmar a exclusão de dados por parte do usuário.

Answer (score 1):

Bem, o negócio é usar ajax mesmo, com jquery fica simples, mas seu código ta ruim de entender

1º coloca um id no seu form, `<form id='f1'>` //arquivo form.php

2º depois separa em dois arquivos, o que tem o formulário e o php que receberá os dados //arquivo recebe_form.php

agora a parte que você perguntou:

`<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $('button').on('click',function(){
              $.ajax({
                  type: 'post',
                  url: 'recebe_form.php',
                  success: function(msg){
                      $('#f1').html(msg); //aqui o msg é o retorno do php, que será o botao que deve ficar visivel
                  }
             });
        });

    });
</script>`

finalizando no php, nao vai usar função

`if($_POST){
     //faz o select para ver se existe o favorito ou nao
     if($existe){
          echo "<button id='remove'>Remove<button>";
          //voce nao vai precisar colocar o if else que tava la no form, assim o codigo fica mais separado
     }else{
          echo "<button id='favoritar'>Favoritar<button>";
     }

}`

Não é o código mais bonito do mundo, mas funciona, já deu pra ter uma idéia eu acho, até mais.